# How to remove a dir with long strange name?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ntfs

Recently some tool have created a directory on my external USB hard drive. The name is too long and contains things that cannot be there at all. Obviously standard Microsoft Explorer (or even Total Commander) cannot delete it. I would just format the disk but I have no enough space to temporarily copy somewhere the data, so it's not an option.

How to remove the dir without losing other dirs and data on the drive?

```
F:\>dir /x
 Volume in drive F is PORTATER
 Volume Serial Number is C200-35B4

 Directory of F:\

04/21/2016  10:11 PM           567,465 HIBERN~1.MAF Hibernate User Guide.maff
11/22/2017  07:08 PM    <DIR>                       Pictures
11/06/2017  08:45 PM    <DIR>                       soft
09/13/2017  12:12 PM    <DIR>          TOPICS~1     topics™
05/21/2020  07:33 PM    <DIR>                       topics™\testing (jUnit, Mockito, QA, Automation)\Selenium\P:\topics™\testing (jUnit, Mockito, QA, Automation)\Selenium\selenium-real-time-examplesinterview-questions
05/21/2020  06:12 PM    <DIR>                       watch
12/10/2014  04:57 PM                32              _.txt
               4 File(s)    167,920,412 bytes
              16 Dir(s)  14,773,325,824 bytes free

F:\>rmdir /S /Q "topics™\testing (jUnit, Mockito, QA, Automation)\Selenium\P:\topics™\testing (jUnit, Mockito, QA, Automation)\Selenium\selenium-real-time-examplesinterview-questions"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.


F:\>fsutil file setshortname "topics™\testing (jUnit, Mockito, QA, Automation)\Selenium\P:\topics™\testing (jUnit, Mockito, QA, Automation)\Selenium\selenium-real-time-examplesinterview-questions" TOPICC~1
Error:  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

F:\>
```

Comment: There are methods here to rename (so shorten) long file / folder names. See if the method can apply to you.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/03882653-42e0-41d1-b3d5-d11609dacf37/cannot-delete-files-file-name-is-too-long

Comment: Prefacing a full path and filename with `\\?\ ` turns of filename checks. `Type "\\?\c:\windows\win.ini"`.

Comment: You might get lucky with **PowerShell**. From a console:`D:<Enter>` > `gci to* | %{ ri -LiteralPath $_.Name -recurse -force }`

Comment: Not to ask the obvious.. but did you run chkdsk on it?

Comment: The NTFS file system supports any name. Windows enforces name checks for Windows programs (maximum 260 characters from MSDos specs). This is so any other Windows program can access the file. Unix or another OS may store illegal names. Windows programs have two ways of opting in to access files without checks. By using a manifest or prefacing the path with `\\?\ `. This is important as many programs only allocate 260 characters of memory to hold the name. Getting a longer name when not expecting it, and it can be up to 32,000 characters, will cause a memory error.

Comment: I would rename the dir "TOPIC~1" to something different and then remove all directories with the name "to*".